# Read each input of the line in Java

Tags: java

I need to be able to read this line with a scanner and separate by each string:

person                 Sara 50000 10000 electrician

So it would print out like:

person

sara

50000

10000

electrician

How would I do that?

Comment: Create a scanner, read a line, split that line into an array, spit each line back out.

Comment: The question formmated wrong wanted each string on a new line

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own or do you just want us to write the code for you?

Comment: I can read the line, I just dont know what to do about the spaces

Comment: Worry less about your question formatting and more about its quality. Please show us your attempt.

Comment: @MasonSmith Look at the javadocs for [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).  It will help.

Comment: after you get the `String` that contains the line, just do `string.split(" ");` to split on the whitespace, and gives you a `String[]`

Comment: Or you could just use `replace` instead of `split`.  But _please_ read the Javadocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's highly recommended if you add some code that you tried!
You have to follow the steps given below. Hope you would better understand if I don't give you the code.

1) Create a scanner

2) Open the file

3) read the line

4) assign the read line into a string variable

5) close the file

6) Split the string with using a blank space (" ")

7) assign the splinted to an array

8) print out through Array

Mow you are done